# numba doesn't appear to work

Tags: python, numba

Here is some code that I wrote to test numba

```
import time
from numba import autojit

@autojit
def triple_count(num):
    start = time.time()
    count=0.0
    r=range(num)
    for i in r:
        for j in r:
            for k in r:
                count += i*j*k

    runtime=time.time()-start
    rate=num/runtime 
    print "%0.4f seconds" % runtime
    print "rate : %0.3f per second" % rate
    print "count: %s" % count
```

The result when @autojit is commented out

```
2.3796 seconds
rate : 126.073 per second
count: 9.0216784125e+13
```

The result when using @autojit

```
0.0000 seconds

rate : 8065969.231 per second

count: 0.0
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I would first start out by timing things differently, not inserting timing calls within the method and instead return the result and then time the method call:

```
from numba import autojit

def triple_count(num):
    count=0.0
    r=range(num)
    for i in r:
        for j in r:
            for k in r:
                count += i*j*k

    return count

triple_count_numba = autojit(triple_count)
```

For `num=200`:

```
In [7]: triple_count(200)
Out[7]:
7880599000000.0

In [8]:triple_count_numba(200)
Out[8]:
7880599000000.0

In [9]: %timeit triple_count(200)
1 loops, best of 3: 747 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit triple_count_numba(200)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.59 ms per loop
```

So the numba produces the same answer as the vanilla python and gets it quite a bit faster. With `num=500` it's 11.5 s vs 106 ms. I'm using numba 0.14.0. You could use timeit programatically in a standard python script, but I'm using it in an IPython notebook using the %magics for convenience.

Comment: Thanks. That does work for me. But still I don't understand why my version doesn't run correctly in numba. It outputs zero! It worries me that it just runs without an error message but gives the wrong answer. Seems very dangerous.

Comment: I actually don't get zero on my machine with your original code. It returns the correct answer. What version of Numba are you using?